# SAP ADO.Net driver not available in VisualStudio 2015 (EF)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ado.net, hana, dataprovider

I am trying to get Entity Framework to work against a SAP HANA database. I got this to work with a SP12 (HANA) client on a SP10 HANA database. However this didn't work bug free. After contacting SAP they told me I needed to downgrade to SP10 client.

After the downgrade for some reason the ADO.Net provider is not available in the explorer anymore. To install the SP10 client I used [this guide](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/7d5922eb50fb481a8d0dd51c4dd3e2b7.html) as reference

> (the guide is available *at SAP Help Portal > SAP HANA Client Interface Programming Reference > The SAP HANA Data Provider for Microsoft ADO.NET > Microsoft Entity Framework Support > Use the Microsoft Database First to an Existing Database with the SAP HANA Data Provider Tutorial*). [EDIT: [old link](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/7d/5922eb50fb481a8d0dd51c4dd3e2b7/content.htm?frameset=/en/46/9e00db6d611014a66fabe7c7ba2b6d/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/f3/5ec71c485e493aa20d0bd0e3bff06a/plain.htm&node_id=90) is broken])

In the fourth step there is a check to see if the provider is correctly installed. This check tells you to run the following command in `cmd`:

```
cd "c:\Program Files\sap\hdbclient\ado.net\v4.5"
SetupNet.v4.5.exe /i /hanalocation "c:\Program Files\sap\hdbclient\ado.net"
```

This returns:

> ```
> HANA ADO.NET Setup Utility Version 1.0.102.0
> Copyright © 2013 SAP AG or an SAP affiliate company. All rights reserved.
>
> Succeeded
> ```

This indicates that the client is successfully installed, however the provider doesn't show in Visual Studio. I already tried reinstalling the client and Visual Studio. This did not seem to solve the problem.

Has any one had this problem before or knows what I might be doing wrong?

Please enlighten me. After 3 days of searching the internet I wasn't able to resolve it.

Comment: The most flexible and stable way of connecting to SAP with .NET is, in my opinion, the web service way. You can convert functionmodules to web services very easily in SAP. Why not use web services instead of this old .NET connector?

Comment: Hi Koen, the decision to go for .Net is made on enterprise level and before i joined the team. I agree that at the beginning of the project your solution would have been preferable. Now that we are already developing for 6 months on the application its to late to make such drastic changes. SAP however is convinced that it should be working although they cannot tell me what i have done wrong.